# How to build a custom Required interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a user type with the below fields and I want to use it with different required fields in many places.
I would like to create a generic type and pass required fields with generic to reduce the boilerplate.

What I have:

```
type BaseUser = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  job: string;
};
```

what I tried:

```
type User<T extends (keyof BaseUser)[]> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K]]: BaseUser[T[K]];
};
```

How I want it to use it:

```
function deleteUser(user: User<['id']> ) { };
function addUser(user: User<['name', 'job']> ) { };
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
type BaseUser = {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  job: string;
};

interface UserDelete {
  id: number
}

function deleteUser<BaseUser extends UserDelete>(user: BaseUser):BaseUser {
  return user;
 };

deleteUser({id: 3}); // works
deleteUser({job: "5"}); // doesn't work because id is required
```

Tsplay: https://tsplay.dev/mpvJpw

Comment: user_id and id are same. sorry, that was a typo. I fixed that.
there are too many use cases. I do not want to declare interface for all of them. It is not clean.

Comment: There you go :)